# PHP code for user after pressing "submit"?

Tags: php, html, forms

before I get started, I would like to thanks this site for making PHP more understandable.  So I'm new to PHP and this is my first time dealing with forms.  In the following code, my goal is to make it so that when the user selects a quantity, and clicks submit, it will open up an invoice table stating how much they selected at how much and with the total.  I've been doing a lot of YouTube and reading, and still can't grasp how to make my page do excatly that.  Please keep in mind, I'm not trying to make it fancy, just very understandable.  Here's my code:)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
               <form action= "<= $_server['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="$_POST">
<?php // **INSERT NAME HERE This code will allow the user to purchase whatever    quantity of certain comic books they want.

      $productImage = array('spiderman1.jpg', 'spiderman2.jpg', 'spiderman3.jpg', 'spiderman4.jpg', 'hulk1.jpg'); // I'm stil lhaving a hard time with multidimensional arrays.
      $description = array('Amazing Spiderman #1', 'Amazing Spiderman #15', 'Amazing Spiderman #52', 'Amazing Spiderman #107', 'Hulk #181');  
      $price = array('400', '350', '150', '300', '90');     

      //the product image array gave me a hard time, in the sense that I'm still having a hard time trying to output an image that saves onto my desktop locally.  So I chose the option of grabbing the links fromt the web.  Don't worry though, I won't do this for my Assignment #1.  UPDATE: Problem has been fixed!     

    echo '<table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="10">'; // I'm very horrible with tables, I finally figured out how to center the text within the table.
    echo "<tr align='center'>
            <td><b>Product</b></td>
            <td><b>Description</b></td>
            <td><b>Price (each)</b></td>
            <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
          </tr>";


    foreach ($productImage as $key=>$display) // I used $key to represent the value to display my images via $display.  If you erase the $display code it would look very nice, but output a bunch of errors.
    {

        echo "<tr align='center'>";
            echo '<td>';
            echo "<img src='".$productImage[$key]."' width='200' height='300'  align='center'>";
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo $description[$key];// Description loop from the foreach()
            echo '</td>';          
            echo '<td>';
             printf('$%', $price); // for some reason if I wanted the price to be $400.00 with '$%.2f', it would print as 1.00400.  So I just kept it as whole numbers swapmeet style.
            echo $price[$key]; // This loops the price  via the foreach() function.
            echo '</td>';          
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<select name="service_type"><br>'; //  my quantity select box, since these are very rare comics
            echo '<option>0</option>'; // started off with 0 because if I gave this first value a 1, then all default comic quantity would be one.  Users will be mad :(
            echo '<option>1</option>';
            echo '<option>2</option>';
            echo '<option>3</option>';
            echo '</td>';

      }
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo 'Add to cart '; // letting the user know what to do after they picked the quantity
            echo '<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" send="invoice.php">'; // my submit button
            echo '</td>';

            echo '</tr>';
     echo '</table>';
    //The images under the description are linked to the websites, if the images are not shown it is due to the image being removed or renamed on the linked site (a disclaimer I borrowed from the assignment webpage.) 

if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) // what I want to do is, if the user clicks submit, it will bring them to their invoice page.
{
    echo "This is your total" . $_POST['submit'];
}


     ?>


        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For one thing, you need to change this `<form action= "<= $_server['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="$_POST">` to this `<form action= "" method="post">`

Comment: It worked!  Didn't know it was as simple as that.  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this solves your problem, but I don't believe that method ="$_post" is correct.  It should be

```
method="post"
```

Then when you need to get data from the form, you refer to the $_POST array.  Hope that helps.

Comment: this made a lot of sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this

```
<form action= "<= $_server['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="$_POST">
```

to this

```
<form action= "" method="post">
```

or

```
<form action= "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```